# Python regarding regex function

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find and replace a pattern in a sentence.

```
Date = 10/20/2018
```

Input -  Sent = " this is data date($date,"info") "

Output - sent  = "this is data 10/20/2018"

I am trying for regex that starts with `"date("`   and ends with `") "`   but that didn't work that way.

Can anyone help me out

Want to replace "date(any data) " in a sentence with some date eg : 20-10-2018

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please separate your text using markdown? For example, it's difficult to determine where the input and output begin. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more info.

Comment: Your example is not clear to me. Please add a clear example and your desired output from that.

Comment: Actually  Input = " the day is date("some data "," other data " ) "

Comment: Input  = " this is date input  date("ABC ","any data " ) "

Comment: Output should replace date ("") with some date. Like output = " this is date 30-06-2016 "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I get what you want. With the following code you grab what is in-between the date():

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"date\((.*)\)")

string = "I am seaching for the date(whatever is in here)"

results = pattern.finditer(string)

print(results)

for i in results:
    print(i.group(1))
```

You do not provide your regex, but I would suspect, that you did not escape the brackets.

```
\( vs. (
```

Comment: Thank you I will check on that

Comment: Actually I don't want which is inside date(). I want to change that date("something ") in a sentence to date ie : date =22-10-2017. Input = "This is a string date("something) " to output = " this is a string 22-10-2017"

Comment: Well, then you can use the same regex just with i.group() to get to the whole thing.

Comment: Please note that as a best practice `.*` should be avoided. In your case, you may use some contrast with something like `[^)]*`. That way it will prevent a lot of backtracking.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it